# How to send file data in post request in node using request module?

Tags: node.js, file-upload

**Requirement**:

I need to make an api call with the file uploaded by the user.My server is node and I use **request** module for making api calls.
Below is the code when user uploads a file and submits it.

```
if(queryData.sub == "upload"){
    var input = {};
    var formidable = require('formidable');
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(request, function (err, fields, files) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile(files.filetoupload.path, function(err, data) {


    input.x_file_content = data;


    client.API.ATTACHMENTS.uploadFile(input).then(function(resp){

        var str = settings.layoutParsing(resp);
            response.write(str);
            response.end();
    })

    });

    });
}
}
```

In upload file function i use FormData to set the file and send it while making api call .Below is the code:

```
if (request.x_file_content) {

            var FormData = require('form-data');
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', request.x_file_content);//No I18N
            req_body = formData;

        }
```

...

```
var httpclient = require('request');

httpclient({

        uri : baseUrl,
        method : request.type,
        headers : api_headers,
        responseType : responseType,
        body : req_body

    },function(error,response,body){
```

**Problem:**

but the file was not successfully sent and multipart content required error is thrown by the api server.

Can anyone point out what mistake Im doing.

**Thanks** !

Answer (score 1):

found out the mistake,

setting header and replaced

```
 fs.readFile(files.filetoupload.path, function(err, data) {
```

with `readStream = fs.createReadStream("path to file");`

rectified code :

```
input.x_file_content = readStream;
```

..

```
var FormData = require('form-data');
            form_Data = new FormData();        
            form_Data.append('file', request.x_file_content);//No I18N           
            req_body = form_Data;            
        api_headers = form_Data.getHeaders();
```